# Spring Application with hibernate running in weblogic serve

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, weblogic-10.x

I have an Spring Application where some queries goes trow hibernate and other using Spring StoredProcedure, the thing is, I'm having problems with the weblogic datasource pool, sometimes the application has errors becasuse there is no resources in the pool and then just crash. I'm not sure about what could be the "Maximum Capacity:" but I'm not sure about how Spring StoredProcedure works, reading the log, I see a lot of new creation of resources for the pool and less closed in comparation.

Any advice about how to control the application new connection request?

Comment: Can you post some logs, code, etc?  Are you closing any datasources/connections you are opening?

Comment: Basically I'm using hibernate for domain entities, Spring StoredProcedure class to call database storeprocedures and a couple jdbctemplate implementation.
So, using this I supposed the connection is hadled by this tools.
The thing is, sometimes the application doesn`t have more  resources from server datasource pool, and this lines are common in the log

Comment: ####<04-oct-2013 13H37' CEST> <Info> <Common> <SERVERDOMAIN> <SERVERDOMAIN> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1380886677558> <BEA-000628> <Created "1" resources for pool "webdba", out of which "1" are available and "0" are unavailable.> 
####<04-oct-2013 13H38' CEST> <Info> <JDBC> <SERVERDOMAIN> <SERVERDOMAIN> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1380886712702> <BEA-001128> <Connection for pool "webdba" closed.>

Comment: Are you using Transactions with JdbcTemplate.  It is right to assume that Spring will close any resources in simple cases, however if you wrap that code in a Transaction and don't either commit or rollback, Spring will never return the resources.  That said, the log message you posted is not an error, it's WebLogic just being "chatty" in the logs.  Its basically logging that it added a new connection to the pool, indicating 1 is available and 0 are unavailable.  I wouldn't worry about Info-level messages from WebLogic.